# Will there be any problems if in my project, I use other sources like image from regular websites?

Tags: open-source

As title.
It is the safest if we go for searching free source and just use them, but it is not always the case that we can find the one that we want. If then, what will happen if I just use images from someone's website in my own project?

Comment: depend on the license.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about intellectual properties / licensing / terms of use / legal issues instead of directly about programming. **[See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)** for details and the **[help]** for more.

Answer (score 0):

Images that you find on the web are licensed in one way or another, as a result it is important to understand the terms of that license.

[This](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/657/what-am-i-supposed-to-do-if-someone-is-breaking-the-terms-of-my-licensed-softwar) question goes over what you can do when your license is being infringed upon.

But from the phrasing of your question it sounds as though you are curious about what will happen if you just take images from other websites regardless of the licences on those images. In most cases, it is unlikely that much will happen as the content owner would have to be aware that you're using their licensed product. *But that doesn't mean that you should.*

If you were using licensed content and the content owner was aware, they have many options available, from requesting that you remove their content all the way to hiring a lawyer to pursue the issue.

I personally do not recommend just using content without knowing what license it is governed by. **It is always better to ask permission first**. That being said, [Here is a link](https://visual.ly/community/infographic/other/can-i-use-picture) to a flow chart that may help in deciding if you should/can use an image from the web.

Comment: Then, what about some free source websites?
I have never published anything before, but I have heard as long as we use the free sources, that should be fine. I am not quite sure how to determine whether it is a free source. I search images on this site [link](https://pixabay.com/) these days. Is this a whole free sources website?

Comment: @Eric [This](https://pixabay.com/en/blog/posts/public-domain-images-what-is-allowed-and-what-is-4/) link may help some, it is from the website you mentioned and it covers the use of images on their site.